# Can't Change Display language in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, display, language

I have Window 10 Home Edition running in LENOVO-Y700, I once restored it 
from the recovery drive but accidentally, I installed it with Danish language.
After that I managed to change the display language to English. But recently an update has been installed and the display language returned to Danish. I tried to change it like I did in the first time but it returns to Danish each time. I tried the recommended ways  [change the language](https://support.lenovo.com/pl/en/solutions/ht117628)  but the problem persists.

How do I persistently change the Display Language on Windows 10 Home?

[[image: picture change the windows lang]

Comment: do you use Home or Home Single Language? Post a picture of running winver.exe

Comment: No it is not Home Single Language because I was able to change it to English , But when an update was installed it returned back to Danish, In addition I have the option of changing the language but the problem is that it doesn't apply.

Comment: I had the same issue. The internet stuff worked for me with English (GB) for some reason, but not with English (US).

Answer (score 4):

The only thing that worked for me was installing the language package manually:

https://www.itechtics.com/windows-10-version-1709-language-packs-direct-download-links/ (installation instructions underneath the download links)

After the language pack is installed:

1. Region and language settings
2. Additional date, time & regional settings (Control Panel\Clock, Language, and Region)
3. Language
4. "Options" next to the language you want to select
5. "Override" / "Change override" and choose the language
6. Apply language settings to the welcome screen, system accounts, and new user accounts
7. Copy Settings
8. Check "Welcome screen and system accounts" and "New User Accounts" if you desire.

Comment: It might be worth [including the download links](https://superuser.com/posts/1308460/edit) (for eg Danish/English/other ones you feel are relevant here) in your answer

Comment: Actually I have solved the problem by reinstalling windows and selecting English as the system language.

Comment: @bertieb Agree, but I'd have to keep them up to date, as they would change with every build of Windows. The site I mentioned adds a link to downloads for the new build if it is released.

Comment: Unfortunately, if you still had that menu in March '18... then you were still running on an early 1709 build... 1709 was the first release to ditch "Clock, Language, Region" for good :-(

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Windows 10 with local account, press Windows + I to access the Settings application.

- Next, choose Time & language and then Region & language.
- After that, select Add a language and then add the language you want to change to. I think it's English, right :). So just choose it from the list.
- Next step, set it as default.
- Press Ctrl + X and choose Control Panel
- Choose Language and then Add a language.
- Next, select Advanced settings -> Apply language settings to the Welcome screen, system accounts, and new user accounts.
- On the Administrative tab, under the "Welcome screen and new user accounts", click the Copy settings button.
- Check the Welcome screen and system accounts and the New user accounts options.
- Click OK
- Click OK again.

Reboot your computer and upon restart, you should see the new default language globally set through the operating system.

For step by step guide with images, [read this article](http://www.windowscentral.com/how-properly-change-system-default-language-windows-10).

Comment: thanks for your answer. However, I mentionned above that I tried most of the ways that i found in the internet, but the problem seems to be more complicated. Because when I try to copy the setting and I hit ok it returns back to danish like it is shown in the piicture above . I also tried to change it from the registry following this tutorial   http://winaero.com/blog/upgrade-to-a-different-language-of-windows-10-from-the-installed-one/      but when I reboot the language returns to its initial value :( I am disoponted because   I don't want to wipe my computer.

Comment: Tried to change it from Safe Mode?

Comment: I've just tried  that but the same behaviour.